# How to shorten the Permalink after WP>WP blog import?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, import

We've imported a blog from one domain to another and the permalink thats been created for category archives is:
domain.com/category/graphic-design-blog/tips-for-artist/
where **category/graphic-design-blog/** is superflous.

The permalink structure is set to the default (2011/10/post-name) and this is working fine for single posts.

Yoast's WP SEO plugin is installed, but there are no changes made under the permalink section of the plugin.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening / how I can fix it?

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry [no-one ;)], I figured it out:

- /category/ can be removed in Yoast SEO by checking '**Strip the
  category base from the category URL.**'
- The other part 'graphic-design-blog' was displayed because all of the
  categories were had the parent 'blog' which had the slug 
  'graphic-design-blog'.  **I set all the sub-categories to have the parent: none.**

Embarrassingly simple :)